# React: How to add classname in material ui makestyle using conditional statement?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a component using react js. I will use a conditional statement to render the classname of a particular element. My problem is I'm using material ui makestyle to select the classname. I can't find a way to attach the dynamic classes into the className={classes.(dynamic classname)}

```
//External CSS
import useStyles from '../../styles/style';

const classes = useStyles();

//JS code for the dynamic classname

<CardActions
                className={
                  currentTask.priority === 'Low'
                    ? 'checkBoxContainerLow'
                    : currentTask.priority === 'Minor'
                    ? 'checkBoxContainerMinor'
                    : currentTask.priority === 'High'
                    ? 'checkBoxContainerHigh'
                    : 'checkBoxContainer'
                }
              >
                <Checkbox
                  icon={<CircleUnchecked />}
                  checkedIcon={<CircleCheckedFilled />}
                  color='primary'
                  className={classes.completAction}
                />
              </CardActions>
```

Output
classname={classes.(classname)}

Comment: Did you mean to write classes.completAction or did you mean classes.completeAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an approach like this

```
//External CSS
import useStyles from '../../styles/style';

const classes = useStyles();

//JS code for the dynamic classname

<CardActions
                className={
                classes[`checkBoxContainer${(currentTask.priority === 'Low' || 'Minor' || 'High') ? currentTask.priority : '' }`]}
              >
                <Checkbox
                  icon={<CircleUnchecked />}
                  checkedIcon={<CircleCheckedFilled />}
                  color='primary'
                  className={classes.completAction}
                />
              </CardActions>
```